# Python re.findall prints list instead of string

Tags: python, regex, urllib2

```
address = ('http://www.somesite.com/article.php?page=' +numb)
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
regex = re.findall(r"([a-f\d]{12})", html)
```

if you run the script the output will be something similiar to this:

```
['aaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbb', 'cccccccccccc']
```

how do i make the script print this output (note the line break):

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccc
```

any help?

Comment: If you're asking about output, you should include the output code.

Comment: It's _supposed_ to return a `list`. If you want it to print one item per line, that's a very basic task that you'll find in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print `regex` like this:

```
print "\n".join(regex)
```

---

```
address = ('http://www.somesite.com/article.php?page=' +numb)
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
regex = re.findall(r"([a-f\d]{12})", html)
print "\n".join(regex)
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall()` returns a list.  So you can either iterate over the list and print out each element separately like so:

```
address = ('http://www.somesite.com/article.php?page=' +numb)
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
for match in re.findall(r"([a-f\d]{12})", html)
    print match
```

Or you can do as @bigOTHER suggests and join the list together into one long string and print the string.  It's essentially doing the same thing.

Source:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0) Return all non-overlapping
>   matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is
>   scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If
>   one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the
>   beginning of another match.

Comment: My code is already in a "for" statement, any alternative solution? thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` on the result:

```
"".join("{0}\n".format(x) for x in re.findall(r"([a-f\d]{12})", html)
```